# Not able to pull all the contacts exposed via Microsoft graph for outlook account

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-api

I have started integrating our code base to use Microsoft graph API, to read the contacts of outlook account as part of a new feature where the user can cherry pick the contacts available so that they can be imported.

For the account I am testing there are a total of 19 contacts available, but when I make the api call, I see only 10 contacts in total ( for sure this is not related to any paging ). Not really sure what is wrong with the contacts which I am not able to pull.

**End point** - `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts`

**Scope**     - `https://graph.microsoft.com/contacts.read`

**Fields**    -`$select=givenName,middleName,surname,emailAddresses,mobilePhone,homeAddress,homePhones`
**Order By**  - `$orderby=displayName asc`

Wondering if any one ran into the issue, where they are not able to pull all the contacts available for the specific account. It would be great if anyone has any pointers for the issue that I am running into.

Comment: Are they all stored in a single Contact Folder?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur They are stored in multiple folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`/me/contacts`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contacts) endpoint will only return contacts in the mailbox's *default* Contacts folder.

In order to retrieve Contacts from other folders, you first need to retrieve the list of available folders using [`/me/contactFolders`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contactfolders). You can then retrieve the Contacts from each of the available folders.

For example, if we had 3 contact folders: `folder1`, `folder2`, and `folder3` then you could make three separate calls to retrieve all of the contacts:

```
GET /me/contactfolders/folder1/contacts
GET /me/contactfolders/folder2/contacts
GET /me/contactfolders/folder3/contacts
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That solved the problem for my use case.